# Why are the axis labelled as such in the 3d Cartesian coordinate system?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, 3d

A long time ago I was taught that in 3d space, the x axis is the length/width or left/right space, the y axis is the height, and the z axis is the depth.

When we draw things in 2d on a page, this seems consistent for x and y:

```
y
 |
 |
 |
 |________
           x
```

Now we have a 3 dimensional grid:

```
   (y)
    |
    |
    |
    |________
   /          (x)
  /
 /
(z)
```

Intuitively, I'd "overlay" the 2d grid over this, so the x would be going from left to right, and the y would be going up and down. z would be the axis extending into and out of the page, which makes sense because that's depth. This seems very consistent

Then why do we label the axis like:

```
   z
    |
    |
    |
    |________
   /          y
  /
 /
x
```

Where did this orientation come from? y is where x used to be, and z is where y used to be. The only "artifact" from 2d is that the positive y axis is 90 degrees counterclockwise from the positive x axis. Where is the consistency? Surely there's some mathematical reasoning behind this? We didn't just cobble it all up to mess with students?

On a side note, the video game Minecraft labels the axis the way I thought would make sense ([y up/down, x east/west, z north/south](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Coordinates)), although it makes z+ south and z- north.

Comment: I think you answered your own question. When we draw 2 dimensional things, we draw them on a page, which sits on the table. How is this page oriented in our universe?

Comment: @N.S. If the page is "naturally oriented" facing up, then wouldn't the conventional way of labelling axis be completely wrong? x is up, y is east/west, and z is north/south? If the natural orientation of a page is upright, then the conventional way says: x is depth or north/south, y is east/west, z is up/down. I could understand z being up/down if y was north/south and x is east/west. The best way I could understand it is for that to happen positive y would have to be behind the page, so they rotated x and y 90 degrees clockwise, but that seems so much worse than just doing it the first way

Comment: No, EW/NS is irrelevant, it is their relative orientation which matters. Rotate your page around $z$ and your axis are oriented the right way, but we cannot draw them this way since  $y$ would be lost under the $z$-axis.....

Comment: @N.S. If EW/NS doesn't matter, why does the natural orientation of a page matter? Also, In the first labelling, x and y are consistent with 2 dimensions, and z comes out of the 2d plane. Why didn't we do it that way?

Comment: That's exactly the point. Be consistent with the 2-D. Can you draw $y$ to N and $x$ to $W$ in plane? If you draw $y$ to $N$ then $x$ MUST be towards E.... And if you stand up, walk around a bit, and look at the paper from a different position, does that mean that the axes suddenly become wrong or are they still right?

Comment: @N.S. I'm not sure what you mean. I could unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean. The second way seems completely inconsistent with 2D

Comment: Just draw the two axes on a paper, put it on the table, stick a needle facing up as the $z$ axis, and go in circles around the table. You'll see that from some position you see exactly the orientation we use...

Comment: @N.S. I just did, and still don't see it. If the point was that n/s e/w are relative, I know that, but would argue there's a benefit to having a consistent labelling system relative to the "default orientation" of the user (for lack of a better word) and page. And btw, I'm interpreting both examples with x and y flat on the paper-plane. They just have different eye perspectives, and I think the way you look at graph 1 is equally (if not more) valid because it's consistent with the way we place it on paper in 2 dimensions

Comment: At the end of the day it doesn't matter, as long as you keep consistent about the RH systems. But, this is more about the following: how do you typically see the $2$-d plane inside the space? Laying flat on the floor, or a vertical wall?  I typically see it as the piece of paper I write on, and that's why my $xy$ plane is horisontal not vertical. And often you study a problem first in 2D and then move to 3 dimensions....

Comment: @N.S. I can see it as both, although I tend to it being on a wall, because I like to see "y" as up (so it's like a circular problem :P ). But with both ways, when I draw it on paper, xy is horizontal. It's just you look at them differently. Like if I visual the second diagram in 3d, then visualize the first diagram with the same perspective, it looks messed up. But if I visualize the first diagram with the same perspective I visualize 2d (but "extend" it another dimension), then the first diagram looks right and the second diagram is off

Comment: @N.S. I was just going to ask a similar question, when I found this; so I was wonderinf if I could get your take on it. I also imagine the xy plane lying down like a piece of paper, like you do. But in 2D, it seems more like a vertical wall; so when I transition from 2D to 3D, the most natural thing that occurs to me is to imagine pushing the wall down, and creating the $z$ axis as the vertical direction; however, this results in the $x$ and $y$ being swapped, compared to the standard. Do you find it intuitive to think like me, and prefer the swapped $x$ and $y$ axes, or do you

Comment: @N.S. find the standard arrangement more intuitive. If the latter, I am curious to know why?

Comment: @Ovi I don't think that in your process $x$ and $y$ are swapped. They are rotated by $90^\circ$ so if you rotate them properly you get the standard configuration... Just look carefully at the (arrow) direction of the axis.

Comment: @N.S. Right, I didn't think about it and I equated swapping $x$ and $y$ with rotating the $xy$ plane. So that's what I wanted to ask; isn't the most natural way to go to 3D by pushing the wall down, which would result (on paper) in a horizontal $x$ axis, vertical $z$ axis, and the $y$ axis coming out of the page? Or am I missing something that makes rotating the $xy$ plane more natural or useful?

Comment: @Ovi Try to draw it that way... The Y-axis would not come out of the page, it would go towards the back. This means it would need to be drawn between x-axis and z-axis, making it very hard to sketch anything... The "axis system" would be be too crowded.

Comment: The truth is there is no requirement that x, y or z axis be drawn in any particular orientation.  I draw them oriented whichever way makes my diagram easiest to understand and interpret.  With the appropriate rotations or flips any diagram can be oriented any way desired.


To prevent confusion, I sometimes label all 6 directions, +x, -x, +y, -y, +z, -z.
Even the right hand rule below assumes X x Y =Z, but the right hand rule could give

Answer (score 0):

In physics, the orientation of the 3D plane is very important. The second way how you graphed it, obeys the Right Hand Rule, an important rule in electricity.
In this manner, the force is pointing in the positive direction of z

Comment: Both ways obey the right hand rule in that a vector in the positive x axis cross the vector in the positive y axis produces a vector in the positive z axis. In fact, the first way I graphed it, the force is "out of the page" which seems like it's even more consistent, although I cannot concretely explain why it seems better to me

Comment: Well, the only other reason I could come up with, is that in the second case, the z-scale is not "warped", since it is a vertical axis. THe axis that comes "out" of the paper has a scale that is drawn differently on paper. Since in a lot of cases, z is an output depending on x and y, I could imagine that they wanted to keep the z-axis with its true scale, otherwise I wouldn't honestly know, other than that I learned it that way, like millions of others...

Comment: Hmmm, was possible it seems like a minor plus compared to the "inconsistencies" it brings. Besides, I don't think "drawn to scale" is ever really important, and when it is (for mechanical engineering and what not) you would draw your blueprints/whatever with enough precision and perspective that it would not look warped

Comment: It may not be such a big issue nowadays with all the technology, but I could imagine in the old days, precize hand made (what else did they have?) drawings were important for whatever engineering purposes it was for.

Comment: but you're still warping the x axis then, so the point that they did it for precision is moot

Comment: Yes, I could see that, but I was thinking that they needed that kind of precision particularly for the output, here the z. Obviously not all three axis can be drawn on paper on exact scale.

Comment: there's also the consideration that in the real world your two vectors are not always in the x/y plane; it could be on the yz plane and it'd be important to get the result on the x

Answer (score 0):

Comment

For a surface of revolution using cylindrical coords and helices one would llke to keep the right hand side going arrow positive as symmetry axis, still sticking to familar cartesian $(y,x)$ going up and out of the page in the RH system intact. So it depends upon the overall object situation in reference also.